# Non-destructive image cropping plug-in

Tags: assets, plugins, image

I am looking for a user-friendly, non-destructive way define an image crop when editing an entry with an asset field.

- Should be able to visually define an image crop
- Should be able to change the crop when editing the entry
- Should not crop/overwrite the original image
- Should not generate a new asset in the asset library for the cropped image

I am aware of the built-in cropping tool, but it is not very userfriendly since it either crops the original asset (destructive) or creates a new asset with the cropped image (confusing and messy). This (A) makes it confusing to edit the cropping (you need to hunt down the original asset and create a new crop) and (B) introduces the need to sanitize your asset folders to remove unused crops.

I am also aware of the [Ansel plug-in](https://plugins.craftcms.com/ansel) which pretty much does what I want but seems to be abandoned by the author. It does not work with Craft>3.1, as acknowledged by its author [here](https://buzzingpixel.com/support/issue/166).

Does anyone know of a third option for this?

Comment: Have you tried using a crop _transform_? You can allow the user to simply set the focal point for each image.

Comment: @LindseyD This would be the easiest solution, but the client needs more precise control over the crop than offered with the focal point